# Python Question : How to update a list which contains customer info in python? The elements in the list contains either yes or no

Tags: python

Say for instance:

#audit of current year

```
name_of_members = ['julia','mike','stacey', 'alex']

is_team_member = ['yes','no','yes','no']
```

Basically, we can see that Julia and Stacey is a members of a team or they are part of a team whereas else Mike and Alex are not in any team.

Now, we have to check if in the next year these people are still team members or not and if they are in a team. basically, we have updated the data of each member.

so we might want to take input from the users that say

```
input("Is Julia still a team member?") #yes/no
```

update "is_team_member" as per input

and the input given will be stored in the index where Julia's data of whether she is a team member or not was stored.

So I want to know how to do this.

Comment: As an aside: python has a boolean type for which you can use either true/false or 1/0. This may serve your needs better than "yes"/"no".

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue:

```
for i in range(len(name_of_members)):
    is_team_member[i]= input("Is "+name_of_members[i]+ " still a team member?")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it

```py
name_of_members = ['julia','mike','stacey', 'alex']
is_team_member = ['yes','no','yes','no']

for i in range(len(name_of_members)):
    if is_team_member[i] == 'yes':
        res = input(f'Is {name_of_members[i]} still a team member? ')
        if res == 'no':
            is_team_member[i] = 'no'

print(is_team_member)
```

I suggest using `dictionary` instead of two separate lists, Where key represents the member's name while the value represents if they are in a team or not.

```
members = {
    'julia': 'yes',
    'mike': 'no',
    'stacey': 'yes',
    'alex': 'no'
}

for name, response in members.items():
    if response == 'yes':
        res = input(f'Is {name} still a team member? ')
        if res == 'no':
            members[name] = 'no'


print(members)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name_of_members = ['julia','mike','stacey', 'alex']

is_team_member = ['yes','no','yes','no']

for i in range(len(name_of_members)):
      data=input(f'{name_of_members[i]} Is still a team member? ')
      is_team_member[i]=data
#using list comprehension
is_team_member=[input(f'{name_of_members[i]} Is still a team member? ')for i in range(len(name_of_members))]
print(is_team_member)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your lists into one dictionary and then replace values in dictionary with responses from input

```
name_of_members = ['julia','mike','stacey', 'alex']

is_team_member = ['yes','no','yes','no']

name_dict={}
#Convert to dictionary
for x in range(len(name_of_members)):
    name_dict[name_of_members[x]]=is_team_member[x]

#Replace answers based on input
for k,v in name_dict.items():
    team_q = input(f"Is {k} still a team member? Yes or No?")
    name_dict[k] = team_q
print(name_dict)
```